# Constructing functions such that integral along any closed curve is non-zero

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-forms

Consider smooth maps $f: \mathbb R^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\} \to \mathbb R$.

How can I construct such an $f$ with the property that

$$ \oint_C f \neq 0$$

for any closed curve $C$ around the origin?

Note that I am aware that $\frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$ has this property but knowing the answer is unhelpful to me as it does not tell me how to find such a function.

> Ideally, I would like to see an answer with $$ f \neq
>  \frac{xdy-ydx}{x^2+y^2}$$

Comment: For *any* closed curve, not just any closed curve containing a certain specified point? I don't think such a form exists.

Comment: If you want any closed curve containing zero, then pick a positive integer $n$ and represent $dz/z^n$ (in the sense of complex numbers) in your real-variable notation.

Comment: @Ian I'm sorry I probably meant to write any closed curve around the origin... let me edit the question.

Comment: You have to consider curves enclosing the origin. Just try to understand what the integral actually represents. The angle wrt to the x-axis should serve as an easy example (though I think it will be just the example you don't wont to see ;-)

Comment: @Thomas I am trying to understand what the integral represents... any hints on how to go about this?

Comment: You may want to look up Cauchy's Residue Theorem which essentially shows you can have nonzero results if you circle around a pole (a division by zero) such as the one you mentioned (division by $x^2+y^2$)

Comment: @JMoravitz Why can you apply a theorem from complex analysis to real functions on the real plane?

Comment: @astudent: You should clarify what you mean by $f:\mathbb R\backslash\{(0,0)\}\to\mathbb R$. Do you mean $f:\mathbb R^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}\to\mathbb R$?

Comment: @sranthrop Yes I'm sorry for the typo.

Comment: Ok, and the path integral is defined by $\oint_C fdx=\int_0^1f(c(t))|c'(t)|dt$?

Comment: @sranthrop Yes, I think so. Or at least I'm not aware of other definitions...

Comment: Ok, but then any $f>0$ will do the job...

Comment: As JMoravitz said, if you want to understand what the integral represents (and your notation is not quite right.. $dx,dy$ cannot be part of a definition of $f$), you need to understand complex analysis.. Specifically the integral of $z \mapsto \frac{1}{z}$ along a closed rectifiable curve in the complex plane. It is non-zero if and only if the curve has non-zero winding number around the origin. When that is translated to $x,y$ coordinates, it would give the result that an integral something like what you wrote is non-zero if and only if the curve has non-zero winding number around the origin.

Comment: Both cases are necessary for it to be interesting behaviour, otherwise as sranthrop said any strictly positive continuous function will have positive integral along any rectifiable path of non-zero length.

Comment: @Ian: Only $z \mapsto z^{-1}$ will give non-zero integral for a path with non-zero winding number around the origin. For any integer $n \ne -1$, $z \mapsto z^n$ has an anti-derivative that is holomorphic everywhere except for the origin, and so the integral along any closed rectifiable path is $0$.

Comment: @user21820 It seems like your comments might become an answer..

Comment: @hjhjhj57: Alright. I thought it wasn't well-written enough for an answer that's why I didn't post it.

Comment: @hjhjhj57: Okay done. I really don't know how much detail I should give.. It's like a summary of a whole complex analysis course!

Comment: @user21820 Well, you can rest assured that you've made this site a better place!

Comment: @hjhjhj57: Thanks! =)

Comment: In the first place, when $f$ is a scalar function defined in some region $\Omega\subset{\mathbb R}^2$ the expression  $ \oint_C f$ does not make sense whatsoever.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Then sranthrop's comment is wrong? It states that any $f>0$ will do.

Answer (score 1):

As *JMoravitz* said, if you want to understand what the integral represents (and your notation is not quite right.. $dx,dy$ cannot be part of a definition of f), you need to understand complex analysis..

Specifically consider the integral of $\int_C \frac{1}{z}\ dz$ where $C$ is a closed rectifiable curve in the complex plane. This integral is non-zero if and only if $C$ has non-zero winding number around the origin. More precisely, the integral is $2 \pi i k$ where $k$ is the (anti-clockwise) winding number of $C$ around the origin.

Note that though some people define winding number via this integral, that is not the most natural. Instead winding number can be defined for any continuous closed curve that does not pass through the origin, by choosing a fine enough partition such that each piece is within a disk that does not contain the origin. This is possible because a continuous closed curve is bounded and uniformly continuous with non-zero distance from the origin, since $[0,1]$ is compact. Then the winding angle can be defined as the sum of the angles subtended by each piece with respect to the origin. It is clear that all sufficiently fine partitions give the same winding angle, and that it is an integer multiple of $2\pi$, so we define the winding number as the winding angle divided by $2\pi$.

When that integral is translated to $x,y$-coordinates by parametrizing the curve by its real and imaginary components, it would give $2\pi i k = \int_C \frac{1}{x+yi} (dx+i\ dy) = \int_C \frac{x-yi}{x^2+y^2} (dx+i\ dy) = \int_C \frac{x\ dx+y\ dy}{x^2+y^2} + i \int_C \frac{x\ dy-y\ dx}{x^2+y^2}$, and we can see that in the final sum the two integrals are real, and hence the first integral is zero and the second is a multiple of $2\pi$ that is non-zero if and only if $C$ has non-zero winding number around the origin.

Note that $dx,dy$ make no sense without the context of $(x,y)$ being along a continuous curve parametrized in some way, in this case $C$ as a function on $[0,1]$. So technically we can't ask for a function defined in terms of $dx,dy$, though we get what you meant.

Both sides of the if and only if statement are needed for it to be interesting behaviour, otherwise as *sranthrop* said any strictly positive continuous function will have positive integral along any rectifiable path of non-zero length.

In general, to get such behaviour you can take any meromorphic function on some domain with only one pole at the origin with a non-zero residue there, that is, its power series expansion has a non-zero coefficient for $z^{-1}$. Then $\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_C f(z)\ dz$ will be the winding number of $C$ around $0$ for any rectifiable closed curve $C$. The reason is that $z \mapsto z^n$ has an anti-derivative on $\mathbb{C} \backslash 0$ for every integer $n$ except $-1$, and power series can be integrated term-wise, so integrating along $C$ will cause all terms to vanish except the $z^{-1}$ term.